# Why await is not working in Async series? How can i implement it?

Tags: node.js, angularjs

Please check the below sample code , await is not working in async eachseries why?how to solve this issue?

```
async.eachSeries(myaccomplishmentinfo, (imgitem, next) => {
            let imgfilename = req.body.userid + '_' + uniqid.time() + '_' + imgitem.order;
            let img1_buff = Buffer.from(imgitem.filecontent, 'base64');
            let data = {};
            data.binaryData = img1_buff;
            data.folderName = 'myaccomplishments';
            data.fileName = imgfilename;
            data.filetype = imgitem.filetype;
            await s3Lib.storeData(data, (res) => {
                myaccomplishmentimgdetail.push({
                    uniqueid: random,
                    filename: imgfilename,
                    filetype: imgitem.filetype,
                    imagetag: imgitem.imagetag,
                    imgorder: imgitem.order,
                    created_at: getdbdate,
                    modified_at: getdbdate
                });
                console.log(res)
                next();
            })
```

Comment: What’s the error

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What is the "issue"?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you need to add `async` to the `eachSeries` function.

Also, don’t use `next` argument you already waiting for it to end, like this:

```js
async.eachSeries(myaccomplishmentinfo, async (imgitem) => {
            let imgfilename = req.body.userid + '_' + uniqid.time() + '_' + imgitem.order;
            let img1_buff = Buffer.from(imgitem.filecontent, 'base64');
            let data = {};
            data.binaryData = img1_buff;
            data.folderName = 'myaccomplishments';
            data.fileName = imgfilename;
            data.filetype = imgitem.filetype;
            await s3Lib.storeData(data, (res) => {
                myaccomplishmentimgdetail.push({
                    uniqueid: random,
                    filename: imgfilename,
                    filetype: imgitem.filetype,
                    imagetag: imgitem.imagetag,
                    imgorder: imgitem.order,
                    created_at: getdbdate,
                    modified_at: getdbdate
                });
                console.log(res)
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this:

```
async.eachSeries(myaccomplishmentinfo, async (imgitem, next) => {
           // do stuff ...
}
```

Notice that the callback function is async now.

Raz's answer looks good too